# How can I code CSS to make Table like?

Tags: html, css

I want to make the Tags list just like this below.
I want to use CSS instead of using Table tag.
How can I do this?

```
Tags: Apple Banana Melon Strawberry Kiwi Orange 
      Pineapple Carrot Onion Tomato Bacon Sandwitch
      SoyBeans Pork Beef Chicken
```

Comment: No, use a table, That is tabular data.

Comment: If I use table it messes the alignment:( I'm using bootstrap so that I don't wanna bother regular table's CSS for other tables.

Comment: It doesn't look like a table. It looks like a list with a heading.

Comment: @Quentin: Yes, a list would be much better for this.

Comment: @Quentin How can I do that if I use list???

Comment: Such: http://jsbin.com/ojives/2/ (based on @Sowmya's answer)

Comment: @Quentin Do you use <aside> tag often in HTML? I never seen that

Comment: @cat — I don't use it often … but that's because I don't often write webpages that are normal documents these days. People keep asking me to write JavaScript apps for smart TVs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="left">
    Tags:
</div> 
<div class="right">
    Apple Banana Melon Strawberry Kiwi Orange 
    Pineapple Carrot Onion Tomato Bacon 
    Sandwitch SoyBeans Pork Beef Chicken 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.left, .right
{
color:#2B91AF;
}

.left
{
  float: left;
  width: 30px; //adjust this width according to your needs
  margin-right: 10px; //adjust this margin according to your needs
}

.right
{
  float: left;
  width: 400px; //adjust this width according to your needs
}
```

Here is a fiddle just because it's nice:
http://jsfiddle.net/VQjGW/

Answer (score 3):

Use `display:table-cell`

**HTML**

```
<div class="table">
  <div class="td">tags</div>
  <div class="td">Apple Banana Melon Strawberry Kiwi Orange Pineapple Carrot Onion Tomato Bacon Sandwitch SoyBeans Pork Beef Chicken </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.table{display:table-row; width:350px; }
.td:first-child{width:10px; }
.td{display:table-cell;  padding:10px; width:320px}
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8msyW/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

For something like this I would advice using a Definition List. You can read a great article on this here: http://css-tricks.com/utilizing-the-underused-but-semantically-awesome-definition-list/

After that it should be easy enough to use css and position the elements like in your example
.

Comment: If you only have one item in the list, it isn't much of a list. DL is a horribly overused element IMO.

Comment: It might be a matter of semantics. I took the liberty to read again about the DL and think there indeed may be better choices. in this example the DT would be the tags: label and the DD would each be a tag. My mistake was that in this example the DD's aren't necessarily a definition of the DT. I can think of better situations to use a DL though, like for example an entry in a dictionary.