# How can I write in CSS if I'm using list tag for this?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to make the Tags list just like this below.
Then I want to use CSS and list tag.

How can I make that?

```
Tags: Apple Banana Melon Strawberry Kiwi Orange 
      Pineapple Carrot Onion Tomato Bacon Sandwitch
      SoyBeans Pork Beef Chicken
```

Comment: I'd mark this as a [duplicate of this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14232167/how-can-i-code-css-to-make-table-like/14232516#comment19744787_14232516) except this is specifically asking about using a list, and the answers given there don't address that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/ojives/2

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<style>
    h1 { font-weight: normal; font-size: 100%; }
    aside { display: table; }
  aside h1 span:after { content: ":"; }
    aside h1,
    aside ul { display: table-cell; }
    aside li { display: inline; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <aside>
    <h1><span>Tags</span></h1>
    <ul>
        <li>Apple
        <li>Banana
        <li>Melon
        <li>Strawberry
        <li>Kiwi
        <li>Orange 
        <li>Pineapple
        <li>Carrot
        <li>Onion
        <li>Tomato
        <li>Bacon
        <li>Sandwitch
        <li>SoyBeans 
        <li>Pork
        <li>Beef
        <li>Chicken 
    </ul>
  </aside>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there any possible way not to use <aside>??

Comment: You can use any wrapper element you like (and should use the most semantically appropriate one). `aside` was a choice made based on guessing what the context was. (Just be aware that the semantics of the h1 will change if you don't use an aside so you might need to change that element too).

Answer (score -1):

You should first end your `< li >` tags.

Second, write a property for your `<asid>` which is: `width : 360px;` to be like you want